# Cloned fabricjs objects seem to bind when fabricjs 1.7.7 or later version is used

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I created fabricjs canvas. Added a line `line` to it then cloned `line` using `fabric.util.object.clone(object)`. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5kfxy5xa/2/) is the fiddle. Everything looks good except both lines seem to bind with each other because both of them trigger `mouse:over` event at the same time when any of them is hovered which I don't want to happen. This issue is only in version 1.7.7 and later. So, how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [object.clone(callback)](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#clone)

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas',{
 width:window.innerWidth,
 height:window.innerHeight,
});
canvas.on("mouse:over", function(e) {
  if(e.target)
  e.target.setStroke('orange');
  canvas.renderAll();
});
canvas.on("mouse:out", function(e) {
  if(e.target)
  e.target.setStroke('red');
  canvas.renderAll();
});
var line = new fabric.Line([10, 10, 10, 200], {
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  stroke: 'red',
  hasControls: false,
  strokeWidth: 3,
  fill: 'red',
  padding: 10
});
canvas.add(line);
line.clone(function(clonedLine) {
  clonedLine.set({
    x1: 50,
    y1: 10,
    x2: 50,
    y2: 200,
    stroke: 'green',
    fill: 'green'
  });
  canvas.add(clonedLine);
},['padding','hasControls'])
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.7/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" >

</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. What is the difference between object.clone and fabric.utils.object.clone ?